# connecting web parts in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, connection, web-parts

I am trying to connect to simple webparts in my sharepoint team site, i need one of the webparts to filter its information based on what it recieves from another webpart

I am using the query string filter webpart and the a list view webpart but no matter how i connect them always i am getting this error

"Web Part Error:  This page has exceeded its data fetch limit for connected Web Parts. Try disconnecting one or more Web Parts to correct the problem."

What should I do and what am I doing wrong

**update:**
 i can connect to web parts on some other pgae, but getting this error on the DispForm.aspx page of a certain item , is webpart connections not allowed there ??!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an issue with creating QueryString filter webparts in sharepoint, when you're not using the Web UI (I'm making an assumption that you aren't).

This fella here has a post about it and how he hacked around the issue.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/0328f1b2-20cd-427f-887a-e2925bd695e3/

Another option is not using the QueryString filter web part at all, and just passing querystrings to a regular web part.

http://mo.notono.us/2008/04/moss-filter-views-through-url-query.html

Comment: well the thing is i am using two of the out of the box webparts these two the listview and the filter webpart both came with sharepoint so why still there is a bug like that,

i am not intending write my own webpart just to show a list filtered by url query

Answer (score 1):

Me too,you look this url
http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepointdesigner/archive/2008/03/26/sharepoint-conference-building-a-sharepoint-designer-mashup-part-1.aspx

Comment: Great article - this one guided me through a similar problem!

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue.

*Problem*

In the sharepoint list, filtered column name in query strng fitlter has been deleted and added new column with same name.

*Solution:* Remove filter and Set current view again in webpart properties. It works fine.

With Regards,
Marees

Answer (score 0):

The page 'DispForm.aspx' usually is a form of a SharePoint list and different rules apply to list-form pages than on pages that do not belong to a Sharepoint list (and the differences are hardly documented). I solved the problem by workarounds; you could use not a ListViewWebPart, but a DataViewWebPart ([Using Query String and Data view WebPart](http://itfootprint.wordpress.com/2007/05/23/using-query-string-and-data-view-webpart/)), or you could avoid the QueryStringFilterWebPart by using URL parameters that the ListViewWebPart understands ([ListViewWebPart Filter Param](http://acsir-englian.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!6BA7474731AF29F8!456.trak)).